# In Jekyll how do I make paginator have canonical url?

Tags: pagination, jekyll

In my Jekyll how do I make my blog paginator have a canonical url?

In my base template I have:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ site.url }}{{ page.url|remove:'index.html' }}">
```

I expect when I go to `/blog/page2/` that the meta data will be `http://www.foo.com/blog/` instead I see `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.foo.com/blog/page2/">`

How can I make the canonical url for all my blog pages be /blog/?

Here is the code for my paginator:

```
<!-- Pagination links -->
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% if page.url contains "blog/page" %}
{% assign canonical = "/blog/" %}
{% else %}
{% assign canonical = page.url|remove:'index.html' %}
{% endif %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ site.url }}{{ canonical }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also allow additional domain in canonical links by using the following snippet:

```
{% if page.canonical_url != nil %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.canonical_url }}"/>
{% else %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}">
{% endif %}
```